# What to use in place of EtherPad? Using php and mySql

Tags: php, mysql, etherpad

I came across EtherPad but found out shortly afterwards that it has been shelved by Google.

Is there something else that I could use that allows people to collaborate on an online document? It must have version control.

Should I redevelop something instead?

Andre

Answer (score 3):

Try [Etherpad Lite](https://github.com/pita/etherpad-lite), its much leighter than the original Etherpad

Comment: Looks good, but I have to compile it. I want something I can add to a website running php and mySQL.

Comment: Etherpad Lite moved here: https://github.com/ether/etherpad-lite but did you find something using php and mysql? I asked a new question here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/15098296/1069083

Answer (score 1):

[TypeWithMe](http://typewith.me/) is a slightly modified version of Etherpad. It's pretty darn good. Oh but, you need to view the document every once in a while or itll get wiped.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend [Google Docs](https://docs.google.com/). You can create new, upload existing, and collaborate online on files like documents, spreadsheets, presentations and drawings. Take a look at their [Youtube page](http://www.youtube.com/docs) for a demonstration.

Comment: Google Docs is the best, but the answer is so short ;)

Comment: @Alfred I've padded the answer out a bit, no idea how much more I can really mention about it!

Comment: The only problem is that people have to use their Google username and password to log in before using a document. I do not want them to have to use two logins for the website. Can I embed a word like document for each item that I want to have a editable description for?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like MobWrite http://code.google.com/p/google-mobwrite/ is a good solution. Just wish it had the versioning information etc that EtherPad had. Does anyone agree or have something better to embed in a PHP and mySQL website?

Answer (score 0):

EtherPad is still available for buidling and deploying and it even have some seldom commits. If you want to use as an user, there are a few deployments of Etherpad (or perhaps modified versions of it) such as:

- [PiratePad](http://piratepad.net/front-page/)
- [MoPad](https://etherpad.mozilla.org/)

Besides that, there is a quite comprehensive list of possibilities in this [wikipedia entry for collaborative text editing software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collaborative_real-time_editor#Real-time_collaborative_text_editing_software)