# Is there an open source project like EtherPad Using php and mySql?

Tags: php, mysql, etherpad

I would like to install a tool like EtherPad on my debian server, that uses PHP and MySQL as backend.

I found [etherpad-lite](https://github.com/ether/etherpad-lite), that is written in [node.js](http://nodejs.org/) and [PiratePad](http://piratepad.net/), which is only an online platform but I would need a script I could install on my server

Comment: so what is the problem? [Questions not to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask)

Comment: those are not written in php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP cannot solve the "collaborative editor problem" easily because it spawns a new process for each visitor of a site so the memory space is not shared meaning you would have too much latency from database read/writes.

So short answer, no, PHP is not going to solve your problem.  Why not just install Etherpad?

Comment: Shared hosts, for example...

Comment: Original post was 7 years ago.  Today if you set synchronous=OFF and journal_mode=OFF, Php only takes about 3ms to write an SQLite database on a modern SSD.  Your DB may go corrupt in the event of a power loss, but since these are just temporary changes, you can wipe and recrate the db on each system startup.

Comment: "Why not just install Etherpad?" BECAUSE: https://github.com/ether/etherpad-lite/issues/6016